# How to correctly clean up after App Designer apps

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

In MATLAB's App Designer, the only editable 'destructor' I have found is the `UIFigureCloseRequest` callback. However, this does not seem to get called in all cases that an App Designer app can be closed. For example, add a `timer` as a property to the app class. If this timer is `delete`d within the `CloseRequest` callback, everything is OK as long as the app is closed by closing its main window.

However, if the app instance is destroyed otherwise – for example by hitting the 'Run' button in the editor –, a stray timer will be left (as can be found with `timerfindall`). This can of course have unintended consequences.

Since the App Designer's app's destructor is greyed out in the editor, how can I add to it to ensure all resources are reliably destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no documented solution to do what you are asking.

The following solution is a "hack", involving editing MATLAB system files.
I am not sure it's a viable solution, you may treat it as a *proof of concept...*

1. Locate the file `appdesigner.js`.
   In my (Windows) machine file location is: `c:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\toolbox\matlab\appdesigner\web\release\appdesigner\`
   (The file looks like an automatically generated code).
2. **Make a backup**.
3. Open the file with a text editor (I am using Notepad++).
   Locate the text `f.createCodeLine("delete(app."`
4. Replace the above text (code) with: `f.createCodeLine("if ismethod(app, 'my_delete'), my_delete(app);end;delete(app."`
   Save the modified file.
5. Execute App Designer (you may have to restart MATLAB).
   In Code View, you will notice the change in the grayed out part:
   `if ismethod(app, 'my_delete'), my_delete(app);end;delete(app.UIFigure)`.
6. Add a public function named `my_delete`.
   Place your clean up code in `my_delete` method.

I tested the solution in MATLAB R2019a.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds interesting. Did you try whether the resulting app is compatible with unchanged versions of MATLAB? Is this persistent (in the sense that one can change MATLAB internals, create an app, and revert back to unmodified MATLAB with the `my_delete` line still there?

Comment: It looks like App Designer rewrites the grayed out code every time it's executed. Make the modification, open existing `mlapp` file, and the modified code is there. Change back, reopen the `mlapp`, and modified code is gone.

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears be to listen to the app's ObjectBeingDeleted event and put your destructor code in the event callback.  This seems to work in R2020a.

See my MATLAB Answer [MATLAB Answers 463498](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/463498-how-can-i-edit-an-appdesigner-s-destructor) for sample code.

Note that UIFigures are handle compatible and thus support the ObjectBeingDeleted event.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).